# How do I transfer my plugin data?

Tags: plugins

Suppose I have a question and answer plugin. And I have my user data (questions and answers) within it. Now suppose I want to transfer those data to a new wp plugin or a theme. How do I do that ?

Comment: that's an interesting question, but if you are thinking of making tables by editing wordpress database for uploading those tables with your plugin data, you'll probably break site. so make sure you backup everything before proceeding anything

Comment: This question is too broad to give any answer. You need to provide more details including the plugins you were using, are going to use, how these plugins store data etc to get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Data should be stored on the DB, so your plugin should be saving all those QA on a table, so should be able to export that table and then you will have to know how the new plugin storages its data (which table and how) and you import there.